# How to plot $y=\frac{1}{(x-4)^{1/3}}$ with mathematical softwares?

Tags: graphing-functions

I tried to plot the function $y=\frac{1}{(x-4)^{2/3}}$ with Maple software. The result was:

[image]

It is easily can seen tht the graph is not correct. But if i try to plot the function $y=\frac{1}{((x-4)^{2})^{1/3}}$ it gives the correct graph:

[image]
ut

Now i understand how to ask plots from Maple.

But wht if i want to plot $y=\frac{1}{(x-4)^{1/3}}$? How to ask it from Maple?

P:S: I tried it with some other online tools such as [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D1%2F%28x-4%29%5E%282%2F3%29) or [this](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/). Same problem occurs with them also.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I have commited a mistake. Actually, the expression $\frac{1}{(x-4)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ is well-defined for $x < 4$. For example $(-8)^{\frac{2}{3}}=4$ in real field. The problem is that Maple (and Matlab too) takes a complex solution, so that only for $x > 4$ the curve is traced. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you look for is the `surd` command.

To plot $1/(x-4)^{1/3}$ in maple you can do like this:

```
 plot(surd((x-4),-3),x=-10..10);
```

The result is

[image: maple picture]

In Mathematica you can do

```
 Plot[Surd[x - 4, -3], {x, -10, 20}]
```

which results in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Maple takes the complex root with less complex argument, so the cubic root of $-1$ is understood to be $e^{\frac{\pi}{3}}$. One possibility is to ask Maple to print a piecewise function, which in the $x\leqslant 4$ region should be defined as $-\frac{1}{(4-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the answer of the (free tool) [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to the instruction `plot 1/(x-4)^(1/3)` with the option `applyAssumption(1,'^_Real')` is as follows:

[image]

But with the option `applyAssumption(1,'^_Principal')`, one gets:

[image]

In the first case, the program plots the function $$x\mapsto\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}|x-4|^{-1/3}&\mathrm{if}&x\gt4\\-|x-4|^{-1/3}&\mathrm{if}&x\lt4\end{array}\right.$$
In the second case, the program plots the function $$x\mapsto\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}|x-4|^{-1/3}&\mathrm{if}&x\gt4\\\tfrac12(1-\mathrm i\sqrt3)\cdot|x-4|^{-1/3}&\mathrm{if}&x\lt4\end{array}\right.$$
which is only natural since $z=\tfrac12(1-\mathrm i\sqrt3)$ solves $z^{-3}=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is, asking the plot of $g(x):=\frac{x-4}{|x-4|}\frac{1}{|x-4|}$ from maple. The result is:

[image]

I saw this method in the textbook [Thomas Calculus 11th ed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HIyP.png)